# Is there a faster way to search whether a value is within an interval given a list of intervals?

Tags: python, search, data-structures

As a part of my code, I have the following problem:
I have the following lists:

```
    intervals = [(1,3), (5,12), (16,20)]
    labels = [[1,2],[1],[2,3]]
```

The first one is a list of sorted, non-overlapping intervals and the second one is the "allowed" labels of the corresponding interval. For example, labels 1 and 2 are allowed in the interval `(1,3)`. Also, intervals have the form [a,b).

I want to find if for a tuple `(t, l)`:

1. `t` is within an interval of the list intervals.
2. `l` is allowed in that interval.

The approach I could think of is to break the intervals list to lows and highs:

```
    lows = np.array([1,5,16])
    highs = np.array([3,12,20])
    find_indx = np.where(lows >= t)
    if len(find_indx[0]) > 0:
         indx = find_indx[0][0]
         if t < highs[low_indx] and l in labels[low_indx]:
              return 'Yes'
    return 'No'
```

Is there a faster/cleaner approach for this problem? Is it faster to use a binary search than a built-in python function?

Comment: Yeah, binary search is `log(N)`, and you can use it here

Comment: Pandas has a binary search function. My main question is if there are overlapping intervals or do they come non-overlapped

Comment: @Primusa: Though it's only going to make a difference if the `intervals` is *much* larger; even with the C accelerated `bisect` module, since linear scans are going to win for smallish `intervals`.

Comment: I suspect you could speed this significantly (for sufficiently large `intervals`/`labels` to test) by making `dict` where the keys are the the `labels`, and the values are the (sorted) ranges allowed for that `label`. It means that instead finding the legal intervals (linear in your code, log in better code), then linearly scanning for those which have the required labels, you can just do `O(1)` lookup in the `dict` to find the ranges, then linear (or log) search the already pruned set of ranges.

Comment: @Primusa the intervals do not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Binary Search on starting intervals to reduce the time complexity of each search to log(N).For example,let

```
label = [10,11]
intervals = [(1,3), (5,12), (16,20)]
```

As the intervals don't overlap,we need to find the first interval start less than or equal to the label's start.

```
    int val = 10;
    int arr[] = {1,5,16};

    int low = 0;
    int high = arr.length-1;

    while(high>=low)
    {
        int mid = low + (high-low)/2;
        if(arr[mid] == val)
            return arr[mid];
        else if(high == arr.length-1 && arr[mid]<val)
            return arr[high];
        else if(low == 0 && arr[mid]>val)
            return arr[low];
        else if(arr[mid]>val)
            high = mid-1;
        else
            low = mid+1;
    }

    System.out.println(arr[low]);
```

Here the output will be 5.Now we can easily check if the given label belongs in this interval or not.